# Prevent webform postback onclick button

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a webform with an asp button that when clicked, needs to perform a function in c#. The function does not affect anything on the page so I do not need a refresh of the page.Is there any way to prevent an asp button from doing a postback? I am not familiar at all with JavaScript so I need to perform this function in c#. Surely there is a way. I have researched but nothing works. CausesValidation="false"' does not work. UseSubmitBehavior=false does not work. And neither does setting the OnClientClick to return false. Keep in mind I am not using JavaScript. Anyone know how?

Comment: Wrap it in `UpdatePanel`. It will still cause a full postback to the server, but user won't notice as the postback will be asynchronous and the page won't reload

Comment: Notice that it will be using JavaScript, as would any other solution. You just won't need to write any yourself.

Comment: Few options. Use JavaScript or change button to standard HTML button or Wrap button in UpdatePanel.

Comment: the UpdatePanel is exactly what I needed and worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a ScriptManager in your Page first,

Then add an update panel which will have all the controls. This will prevent the entire page being posted back.

here goes an example

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHelloWorld" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHelloWorld" Text="Click the button!" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnHelloWorld"     OnClick="btnHelloWorld_Click" Text="Update label!" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to monkey with the ScriptManager or the server side stuff, you can always use an HTML control as in:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Do Something" onclick="doSomeFunction(); return false;" />
```

OR

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="doSomeFunction(); return false;">Do Something</button>
```

I did discover that attaching the click event to a button element via jQuery will result in a postback (at least that's what happened to me), so I switched to the tried and true input element.